# Bypass Key Event And Pass Value to URL In C#

Tags: c#, .net

Currently, I have a windows application in which some gamification process is to be done by user and after that there is a QR code displayed. After scanning this QR code via a USB scanner connected to windows machine, a URL is generated and some values are added to the URL (just like auth ID OR session id).

My question is: How to bypass the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key hit after scanning the QR code?

Currently, after hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key the values are concatenated to the URL. I want to bypass this <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key hit and as soon as the QR code is scanned further process should be done i.e. values should be added to the received URL

Below is the code which I have - hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and then proceed further:

```cs
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Keydown
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    string url = "";                
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && tb.Text.Length > 10 && onlineStatus) //  
    {
        if ((tb.Text.Substring(0, 7) == "http://") || (tb.Text.Substring(0, 8) == "https://"))
        {
            url = tb.Text;
        };
        if ((tb.Text.Substring(0, 7) == "http>&&") || (tb.Text.Substring(0, 8) == "https>&&"))
        {
            url = convertString(tb.Text);
        }
        LoggerApp.Add("TextBox_KeyDown in url=" + tb.Text);
        LoggerApp.Add("TextBox_KeyDown out url=" + url);
        if (url.Contains("SOME-URL-HERE.at"))
        {
            Console.Write("SENDER-HERE " + sender);
            browser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            scanerReadStatus = true;
            onShowVideoStatus = false;
            RestarttimerUserActivity();
            NavigateApp(url, "");
            tb.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically wand have software that come with it and you can modify the end character key sent by the wand with it. Most if not all wands use enter as the end character so it's not uncommon at all. I have worked with tons of scanners and never got one that couldn't be modified with the software.

Comment: @Franck not sure If I am able to understand what you are trying to explain ...

Comment: Your wand / scanner has a brand. That brand have a software with maybe driver and tools to update the firmware and such on it. That tools also has options to set the character to add before what is scanned and after the scan. Usually the prefix is empty and suffix is an `Enter`. You can change either.